# Что происходит в оперативной памяти при прибавлении 1 к максимальному значению переменной?

Tags: математика

Есть int  с максимальным значением 2147483647. В оперативке выглядит так:

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
```

При прибавлении единицы число превращается в -2147483647 и

```
01111111111111111111111111111111
```

Из-за чего Происходит смена именно 1ой ячейки? Как выглядит этот процесс?

p.s. *буду благодарен тому, кто посоветует подходящую метку*

Comment: Это объяснимый нормальный компьютерный процесс. Так что троллить здесь нечего

Comment: Тут нет троллинга- мистика рулит.

Comment: Блин, ну кто плюсанул ? (((  
Мне медальки "Давление коллектива" не хватает (((

Comment: [арифметика]?

Comment: Ответим троллингом на троллинг! Держите мой плюс!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Никакой мистики, просто [дополнительный код](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0)). У вас небольшая ошибка: число 2147483647 в дополнительном коде выглядит как 0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 (31 единица), а -2147483648 - 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 (единица и 31 ноль).

Comment: Т.е 1 - минус, а 0 - плюс (в первой ячейке)?

Comment: @danpetruk: да, старший бит определяет знак знакового целого.

Comment: @for1ton, вот в Вашем ответе никакой мистики, а в вопросе (предполагая, что автор правильно изобразил единички и нолики) сплошная мистика.

Но, я согласен, автор просто путанул в цифрах.

Answer (score 8):

Никакой мистики нету, это всё определяется стандартами языков программирования.

В C++, например, переполнение *знакового целого* является undefined behaviour, то есть, программа некорректна, и может случиться всё, что угодно, включая получение того ответа, который вы ожидали, любого другого ответа, снос операционной системы и появление привидений из дисковода. Обычно, однако же, n-разрядные целые в C++ (да и во многих других языках) ведут себя как остатки по модулю 2^n: при вычислении "переполненного" значения разряды старше n-го просто отбрасываются. Для вашего случая, `2147483647` (двоичное `0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`) превращается в `-2147483648` (двоичное `1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`).

Но надеяться на это не стоит: компилятор имеет право воспользоваться тем, что в случае UB он может генерировать любой код, для более [мощной оптимизации](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html).

Заметьте, что переполнение *беззнакового целого* в C++ — определённая и допустимая вещь: при переполнении число "законно" заменяется на остаток при делении на 2^n.

---

В C# стандарт языка диктует другое правило: в *непроверяемом* контексте переполнение приводит к неявному взятию остатка по модулю 2^n; в *проверяемом* же контексте переполнение приводит к исключению.

[Пример](http://ideone.com/s0o0Om):

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int maxint = 2147483647;
        int increased1 = unchecked(maxint + 1);
        Console.WriteLine("increased1 = {0}", increased1);
        int increased2 = checked(maxint + 1);
        Console.WriteLine("this will never be reached");
    }
}
```

Здесь работает только первое переполнение, программа выдаёт

```
increased1 = -2147483648
```

после чего срабатывает исключение.

---

В Java переполнения примитивных типов исключены стандартом, результат не отличается от C# в непроверяемом контексте.

Comment: небольшая поправка: хотя это зависит от аппаратуры, отрицательных чисел обычно на одно больше, чем положительных и
1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 это -2147483648 в дополнительном коде,

Comment: @sercxjo: точно, спасибо! Сейчас исправлю. Если я не ошибаюсь, стандарт указывает значение вне зависимости от аппаратуры. Если аппаратура не поддерживает дополнительный код, компилятор вынужден его эмулировать.

Comment: С эмулировать ничего не должен, а если вы про C# или java, то не знаю, может там по-другому. По-моему в стандарте С указано, что для long должен быть обеспечен диапазон от -2147483647 до 2147483647 , но возможны и другие значения в зависимости от аппаратной части, а int - вообще просто самый быстрый целый тип для данной аппаратуры, может быть где 16, где 32, а где и 64 бита.

Comment: @sercxjo: Должен-должен. [Стандарт](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), 3.9.1/4:

> Unsigned integers, declared `unsigned`, shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo `2^n` where `n` is the number of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer.

Это значит, что переполнение должно вести себя как обрезание старших битов в дополнительном коде (вне зависимости от аппаратуры).